# If I went to Korea for two weeks and plan to go again am I using the same 90 day allowance?

Tags: visas, south-korea

I went to Korea earlier this year for two weeks and I plan to go again for three months. However, it just crossed my mind that I can only go up to 90 days without a visa, so, because I went earlier in the year are part of my visa free days already used?

Comment: Linked but not a direct duplicate:  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64193/can-i-leave-south-korea-to-reset-the-90-days-visa-counter

Comment: What visa do you have and what citizenship? Please update your question.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.

Answer (score 0):

The [Immigration Guide - Foreigners](https://www.hikorea.go.kr/pt/InfoDetailR_en.pt?categoryId=2&parentId=385&catSeq=401&showMenuId=375) doesn't say **how long** after the first visit that you can reenter.

The amount of time may be of importance, so I would add at least the month to your question.